# Target div id dynamicaly created inside containers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask for help with some more efective and universal solution for my problem

I have something like gallery, which is continually loads "pages"

the structure looks like this:

```html
<div class="pageseparator"></div>

<div id="searchpage0">
   <figure id="0-1" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="1-1" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="2-1" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="3-1" class="imgrid"></figure>
</div>

<div class="pageseparator"></div>

<div id="searchpage1">
   <figure id="0-2" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="1-2" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="2-2" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="3-2" class="imgrid"></figure>
</div>

<div class="pageseparator"></div>

<div id="searchpage2">
   <figure id="0-7" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="1-7" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="2-7" class="imgrid"></figure>
   <figure id="3-7" class="imgrid"></figure>
</div>
```

And what I actually want:
I click on some figure. I open a record, that is represented by the figure (all on one page, everything handled with jquery and async loading from server).

And then, I need to implement Arrows (buttons), that will show NEXT or PREVIOUS record

So I need to save the ID of currently clicked figure. On NEXT/PREV button, I need to loop through all the structure and find NEXT or PREV figure, get its ID and do a .trigger("click"); (figures has onclick loading its record to another part of page)

But all figures are created dynamically and even there is a known logic of generating its IDs (I dont know, if on 2nd searchpage will be 0-2, 1-2... or 0-7, 1-7... or anything else), it would be quite hard to implement, like:

```
I am at 1-1. Does 2-1 exists?
Yes - save current ID, trigger click
No - Does Next Page exists?
    YES - find first figure, save ID, trigger
    NO - Find the very first figure in the very first searchpage, save ID, trigger
```

So please. Is here any solution, that is less process time consuming, with less code lengt, and generally more pro-like?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement or [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this you can make a [Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html) . And later you can generate click of each carousel item to popup a box where you could use AJAX to get the data.

So instead of having multiple divs with multiple figures, you will have one div enclosing all figures shown 4 at a time or any number of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not a solution. It is quite large project, almost done, only need to implement new feature over an existing DOM. Therefore, no other plugins available for me at the moment. Need to just programatically achieve correct targeting over structure above.

Comment: Then on click of figure, use  parent() method to get refrence of parent div and later use find() with id or class as parameter (of the next div) . Hope this helps